# Pandas - how to assign labels to unlabeled columns in a data file

Tags: pandas

I have a large datafile consisting of six columns of data, each column is unlabelled (lacks a header at the top of the file with column names), that I want to perform analysis on. How do I read in the data and assign names to each of the columns? Considering the following:

```
dgold_names = [ , , , , , ]
dgnew_names = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
dg.rename(columns = dict(zip(dgold_names,dgnew_names)), inplace = True)
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: if you read your data using `.read_csv()`, you can use the parameter `names` to pass the column names, like this `.read_csv('data.csv', names=[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']`

Comment: Hi @dzakyputra, Even that worked for me but is there any other ways to do it.? Please post if anyone have any alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `key` can not be duplicated, we can split them, assign and `concat` back

```
df1=df.loc[:,df.columns=='']
df2=df.loc[:,~(df.columns=='')]
df1.columns=df1.columns=list('ABCDEF')
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```